# Express js 4 routing directly using function pointer from other file returns 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, routes

This seems like it should be so simple. The functions to handle the routes are in a separate file. However after requiring that file and passing the function pointer to the `app.get` it returns a 404 instead.

I have a simple file that exports an object with the function as a key.

src/controllers/Block.js

```js
module.exports = {
  getBlocks: (req, res, next, body) => {
    res.send('blocks')
  }
}
```

Then in the index file I create a basic Express app and import that Blocks.js file. I use the `getBlocks` function for the `/blocks` route.

src/index.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const block = require('./controllers/Block')

const app = express()
const serverPort = 3000;
app.get('/blocks', block.getBlocks)
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  res.send('home')
})

app.listen(serverPort, function () {
  console.log('Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort, serverPort);
});
```

So while `block.getBlocks` is clearly a function it still returns a 404 when you visit `localhost:3000/blocks`. However when you visit `localhost:3000/home` it renders "home" as you would expect.

What on earth am I missing here?

Comment: @NO_GUI it's shown in the code snippet above. This is a curious case ... Keen to find out what the issue was. It all looks fine to me

Comment: Can you try adding `next()` after each `res.send()` call in both routes? (You're going to have to add it to the function arguments for the `/home` route)

Comment: Maybe the parameter res isn't being passed to getBlocks?

Comment: It is tho as this is what express does... very curious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I installed this locally and played around and this made it work:

src/controllers/Block.js

```js
module.exports = {
  getBlocks: (req, res) => {
    res.send('blocks')
  }
}
```

Removing the `body` argument. I am unable to explain this tho.

Comment: WHAT?!?! Yes that absolutely worked. It must be because for `app.get` the 4th parameter is not passed (makes sense). Though I didn't realize that initially. Since you mentioned this I tested again using `getBlocks(...args){ ... }` and there are certainly only 3 args. ok good to know!

Comment: Yeah weird hey. Adding an attribute should not break a function call.